# delphi devexpress how to dock Tform in dxdockpanel at runetime (SDI project)

Tags: delphi, dock

I have an SDI project, I want to dock a form in TDxdocpanel dynamyqe
in C# it's easy

`dxdocpanel.contols.add(myform);`

However in Delphi I find a lot of difficulty,especially with this error

**project raised exception class EInvalidOperation with the message 'Control 'TdxDockPanel($0CD5E660)' has no parent window. Path :
f_main
.TdxDockPanel($0CD5E660)'.**

```
dockme(f_matriels);


procedure Tf_console.dockme(mform:tform); 
var 
Apanel:TdxDockPanel; bts:TdxCaptionButtons;
begin
Apanel:=TdxDockPanel.Create(self);   
Apanel.CaptionButtons:=[cbClose];  
Apanel.AllowFloating:=false;  
Apanel.DockTo(dxDockSite1,dtClient,0);   
mform.Dock(Apanel,mform.Canvas.ClipRect);   
Apanel.show;


end;
```

Comment: You say: ***... but on delphi I find a lot of difficulty***. It would help to understand your problem if you would explain what difficulties you find. Please include all relevant details.

Comment: Such as error messages or what happens